# "Unable to verify account name or password" in Mail app despite using correct info

Tags: mail.app, keychain, accounts, verify

I had a problem with my Mac mail account and therefore I deleted some 4 keychain entries from my Keychain Access that were related to mail. I added a new one:

[image]

I tried to add my Yahoo account again, but this happens:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo has added more security and so does not work with a simple IMAP login by default.

Yahoo's information is [here](https://uk.help.yahoo.com/kb/account/SLN27791.html?impressions=true)

I think to use MacOS Mail you need to follow step 3

> While changing or upgrading your third party applications, you can temporarily give them access.
>
> 1. Sign in to Yahoo Mail.
> 2. Go to your "Account security" settings.
> 3. Turn on Allow apps that use less secure sign in.
>
> Caution - Do not use this setting as a permanent access method. It is intended only for temporary access while you switch or upgrade to a secure application. Remember to turn it off afterwards.